# PCA clustering and creating a new covariate for RNAseq

Tags: clustering, pca, genetics, variable

I am currently doing an RNAseq experiment and some quality control on data. I noticed that there seems to be some kind of batch effect that I cannot explain from the variables I already have. I've attached my plot below that models a known batch effect and variable of interest.

I'm wondering if you think it is okay to create a new covariate (batcheffect2) with the ones outlined in the black box as "1" and everything else as "2" in my regression model? Or maybe use the remove batch effect from limma to do the sample?

The variables being modelled in the figure below are [number of mutations]:[batcheffect1]

Thank you for all the help! Much appreciated. 
[image: PC plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removeBatchEffects() may be okay for PCA, but not for regression. The limma documentation includes this note:

> This function is not intended to be used prior to linear modelling.
>   For linear modelling, it is better to include the batch factors in the
>   linear model.

Batch effects should generally be treated as random effects, but duplicateCorrelation() seems to be the approach used for limma. There is a thread discussing this function with respect to batch effects [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/77093/).